# Get the rows which are missing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am able to get the headcount of total values which are present in the first table not present in the subsequent one. I want to be able to see the actual rows which are present (decisive ones) from the first table. Once I remove the `count` and run `*` my code blows up.

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM act18.users)
 -
(SELECT COUNT(*)
from amp.defines, tax.apps
WHERE tc_user_apps_enroll.user_apps_id = tc_user_apps.ID
AND tc_user_apps.db_year = 2017
AND enroll_years = 1)

The result:

20585
```

When I remove the `count` and attempt to view the 20585 rows, it spills the following error(s) for both the subqueries.

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

I request your assistance in retrieving the `20585` rows.

How can I get the rows from only the first table? Any insights anyone please!!!

Comment: Your table names don't match the columns in the subquery.

Comment: what is the column in the first one that matches the rows in the second one

Comment: @Hogan I have a column in the first table..`my_id` which I am unable to find the matching column for in the second query.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `NOT EXISTS`.  The following is the structure of the query:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM act18.users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM amp.defines d JOIN
                       tax.apps a
                       ON a.user_id = u.user_id
                  WHERE d.user_apps_id = a.ID AND
                        a.db_year = 2017 AND
                        a.enroll_years = 1
                );
```

I have just randomly guessed where the columns come from.  That information is not clear from your question.

Note that I also fixed the `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: I don't think he knows what the matching column is based on the answer to my question in comments -- maybe there isn't one.  :/